# Need help to get a date format

Tags: string, swift, parsing, datetime, format

I am working on an app in Swift and I need help to parse a date.

Basically, I want to get the current date from the phone, and the date two weeks away from it. Also, I want it to be displayed like this:

"2016-3-24T15:50:55.4853116+02:00"

I have no experience at all formatting dates in swift, I only have this in Java and C#.

Comment: NSDateFormatter class reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/

Comment: Dear close-voters: Why is this off-topic? Manipulating date-time is a common programming task, and a surprisingly tricky one. Perfect fit for StackOverflow to my mind.

Comment: The date formats are the same in Java and C# as in Swift because they all come from the same Unicode standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to get the date 2 weeks from today:

```
let secondsInADay: NSTimeInterval = 24 * 60 * 60
let twoWeeksFromNow = NSDate(timeInterval: secondsInADay * 14 , sinceDate: NSDate())
```

Use NSDateFormatter to control how to output the date in a specific format, as Eric D. mentioned.